# C: (Working But Not As Intended) My determinate method is editing the provided matrix (as a parameter) but I just want it to provide the determinate

Tags: c, matrix

Here is my code for the determinate function:

```
double getDeterminate(Matrix m) {
    //We don't want to change the given matrix, just
    //find it's determinate so use a temporary matrix
    //instead for the calculations
    double **temp = m.matrix;
    int rows = m.rows, cols = m.cols;
    //If the matrix is not square then the derminate does not exist
    if(rows == cols) {
        //If the matrix is 2x2 matrix then the
        //determinate is ([0,0]x[1,1]) - ([0,1]x[1,0])
        if(rows == 2 && cols == 2) {
            return (temp[0][0] * temp[1][1]) - (temp[0][1] * temp[1][0]);
        }
        //Otherwise if it is n*n...we do things the long way
        //we will be using a method where we convert the 
        //matrix into an upper triangle, and then the det
        //will simply be the multiplication of all diagonal
        //indexes
        int i, j, k;
        double ratio;
        for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            if(j>i){
                ratio = temp[j][i]/temp[i][i];
                for(k = 0; k < rows; k++) {
                    temp[j][k] -= ratio * temp[i][k];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    double det = 1; //storage for determinant
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        det *= temp[i][i];
    }
        return det;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my struct for the Matrix (in an external header file):

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

typedef struct Matrix {
    int rows;
    int cols;
    double ** matrix;
} Matrix;

/** Build/Destroy/Display Methods
-------------------------------------------*/
Matrix buildMatrix(int r, int c);

Matrix displayMatrix(Matrix m);

/** Matrix Get and Set
-------------------------------------------*/
void setValue(Matrix m, double val, int r, int c);

double getValue(Matrix m, int r, int c);

/** Matrix Multiplication
-------------------------------------------*/
Matrix multByValue(double val, Matrix m);

Matrix multByMatrix(Matrix mat1, Matrix mat2);

/** Matrix Inversion
-------------------------------------------*/
Matrix invertMatrix(Matrix m);

/** Matrix Determinate
-------------------------------------------*/
double getDeterminate(Matrix m);

/** Matrix Transpose
-------------------------------------------*/
Matrix transpose(Matrix m);

#endif
```

Currently it is doing exactly what I want it to do, finding the determinate by turning the matrix into an upper triangle. However, when I run the determinate method, it still changes the matrix I provided as a parameter, even though I believe I used temporary variables to do the calculations without messing with given Matrix.

Example In my main.c I have this:

```
Matrix mat2 = buildMatrix(3, 3);
setValue(mat2, 12, 0, 0); setValue(mat2, 4, 0, 1); setValue(mat2, 3, 0, 2);
setValue(mat2, 4, 1, 0); setValue(mat2, 13, 1, 1); setValue(mat2, 25, 1, 2);
setValue(mat2, 78, 2, 0); setValue(mat2, 8, 2, 1); setValue(mat2, 9, 2, 2);
displayMatrix(mat2);
printf("Determinate of mat2 is %4.2f", getDeterminate(mat2));
Matrix mat4 = transpose(mat2);
displayMatrix(mat4);
```

And when I run it I get:

```
Mat2 Before Transpose
|    12.00    4.00    3.00|
|     4.00   13.00   25.00|
|    78.00    8.00    9.00|

Determinate of mat2 is 3714.00

Mat4 After Transpose of Mat2
|    12.00    0.00    0.00|
|     4.00   11.67    0.00|
|     3.00   24.00   26.53|
```

As you can see the transpose function is doing it's job correctly, but mat2 has been changed by the determinate method. I don't want that to occur, so what have I done to cause this to happen, and what can I do to fix it? I think it has something to do with pointer, I am new to C, so I don't really know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is called `shallow copy`. 
Here: `double **temp = m.matrix;` you just assigned pointer to memory that hold your matrix's elements to the `temp` matrix, so when you edit it, it edits the data that your original matrix holds as well. That's because the original elements only exist a t one place, and poth `temp` and `m` pointers are pointed to it.

In order to do it the way you want it, you have to create a `deep copy`. You have to allocate new memory for the `temp` matrix and copy every single element from the original one into it. Don't forget to `free()` the memory, if you will allocate it dynamically, once you are done with it.

Comment: Ok thank you, will give it a try when I get home. Thanks for the advice, is there a good article or tutorial where I can read up on shallow and deep copies? Also if you are willing to answer, does my C code look good, or are there so very obvious bad practices in there.

Comment: You can find some info in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy) SO post. Your code looks fine to me, except for code formating sometimes.